# Falling through terrain everytime i crouch UNITY3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

in unity i made a script for my guy to crouch, run , and have his regular speed but when i crouch i just fall forever into the terrain was wondering if it is my code or i have to put a check on the terrain.

```
var walkSpeed: float = 7; // regular speed
var crchSpeed: float = 3; // crouching speed
var runSpeed: float = 20; // run speed

private var chMotor: CharacterMotor;
private var ch: CharacterController;
private var tr: Transform;
private var height: float; // initial height

function Start(){
chMotor = GetComponent(CharacterMotor);
tr = transform;
ch = GetComponent(CharacterController);
height = ch.height;
}

function Update(){

var h = height;
var speed = walkSpeed;

if (ch.isGrounded && Input.GetKey("left shift") || Input.GetKey("right shift")){
    speed = runSpeed;
}
if (Input.GetKey("c")){ // press C to crouch
    h = 0.5 * height;
    speed = crchSpeed; // slow down when crouching
}
chMotor.movement.maxForwardSpeed = speed; // set max speed
var lastHeight = ch.height; // crouch/stand up smoothly 
ch.height = Mathf.Lerp(ch.height, h, 5*Time.deltaTime);
tr.position.y += (ch.height-lastHeight)/2; // fix vertical position
```

}

Comment: does the character fall while you press crouch or after you let the key go?

Comment: am i the only one to cringe at the line: if (ch.isGrounded && Input.GetKey("left shift") || Input.GetKey("right shift"))? Please add a bracket, and i'd also advice to not use variable names like ch, tr or h. Everything that improves reading code is worth the extra time spent writing it when you get to debugging ;)

Answer (score 0):

This line could be responsible:

```
tr.position.y += (ch.height-lastHeight)/2;
```

you might want to let gravity take care of this or add a downward Force here. Changing the transform directly makes the Object dont care about colliders in the way.

edit: a better way would probably be to change the CharacterController though, as "falling down" when crouching doesnt make much sense. Maybe you dont even need this? The way i would implement this is the root at the feet, and height goes upwards from there.